# What do my DLC packs contain?

Tags: dungeon-defenders-2

I bought DD2 last year around Christmas together with the following 3 dlc packs:

- 7 Premium inventory bags
- Dragonfall Defender upgrade
- Early Access rewards

I only just got around to playing it and I have no idea what my DLCs do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the [game's Steam page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/236110/):

Dungeon Defenders II Early Access comes with:

- $30 in-game currency
- 4 Exclusive Hero Accessories
- 7 Premium Inventory Bags [Limited Time Offer, Expires 5/5]
- $6 in-game currency & Exclusive “Veteran Defender” Title for owners of Dungeon Defenders or Dungeon Defenders Eternity [Limited Time Offer]

The collector's edition comes with some additional things, which are also mentioned on the store page.